# Loading npm registry ca certs from environment to npmrc

Tags: node.js, ssl, ca, .npmrc

In order to use private npm registry I am trying to setup credentials and ca certs in project's **.npmrc file** .

like following:

```
ca[]=<ROOT_CA> # NOTE this needs to string in double quotes, with newlines replaced be \n
ca[]=<INTERMEDIATE_CA> # NOTE this needs to string in double quotes, with newlines replaced be \n
```

And it works absolutely fine.

But when I move these values to system environment (Mac OS .zshrc) & try to read like following :

```
ca[]="${NPM_REG_ROOT_CERT}"
ca[]="${NPM_REG_INTERMEDIATE_CERT}"
```

It gives me error like following

```
npm ERR! code UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
npm ERR! errno UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
npm ERR! request <complete path to dependency> failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate
```

I have ensured the env values are available & everything works fine (other login credentials are also coming from environment only).

These CA certs are having issue while loading from system environment !
If I disable strict-ssl things work. It means other credentials are loading correctly from system environment .

**Am I missing something here ?**

*Could it be related to format of CA cert string stored in system environment*. I am setting it as base64 string having newline replaced with \n.

Please help.

Comment: I doubt, it is replacing \n to line break while reading from env & that's causing this issue.
I am not sure.